# I am looking for a noun for what is washed up on the beach by the tide

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns

Something like residue, but more specific for what's washed in by the tide. 
Many thanks

Comment: [*tidewrack*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/tidewrack). If the source is an abandoned or sunken vessel it may be in law [*flotsam*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/flotsam) or [*jetsam*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/jetsam).

Comment: @KarlG By gum, it never occurred to me this had been asked before.

Answer (score 0):

If it is like a layer of dirt or slime or some other substance that was floating on the surface of the water, then washed ashore, you might call it **scum**. Since *scum* originally meant *foam*, the substance might well look foamy. But it depends on what kind of residue you mean, exactly.